# ReferenceError: jsreport is not defined

Tags: jsreport

Here i used the jsreport in my nodejs application while download the report in pdf or Excel format i got this error, but all the dependencies are having in my application under jsreport folder.

```
[For your reference i attached the error message ]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3geY.png
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the recipe "html-with-browser-client" to html in jsreport studio in our local machine